# Merging two Notepad++ files and then overwriting into one of them

Tags: notepad++, combine

This question may sound peculiar but how can I merge two files (with changes) in one text?

For those who don't understand the complex diagram, I have text on file 1 and file 2. I need to merge those two files into one file but with File 2 overwriting its changes on File 1 but with its text still preserved.

I have the same lines on both texts that I need to merge with the help of the Compare Plugin showing empty lines and overwritten statements. I just need to merge them into one file.

File 1 (Old File)

```
Line 1 I have a box of (Apples)
Line 2
Line 3 I'm the text from Text 1
Line 4
Line 5 Text (with) Comment
Line 6 
Line 7
```

File 2 (New File)

```
Line 1 I have a box of (Oranges)
Line 2 I have a text here on Text 2
Line 3 I'm the text from Text 1
Line 4 I have a text here on Text 2
Line 5 Text (without) Comment
Line 6 I have a text here on Text 2
Line 7 I have a text here on Text 2
```

Combined Text

```
Line 1 I have a box of (Oranges)
Line 2 I have a text here
Line 3 I'm the text from Text 1
Line 4 I have a text here
Line 5 Text (without) Comment
Line 6 Text with Comment
Line 7 I have a text here
```

Edit: [Here is another example in a sample code. Sorry for confusions Code is not mine, just an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHkrI.png)

Comment: I looked at the image and the description, but can't make sense of what you want to do.

Comment: Me neither. The combined text seems very random, unless it contains errors. For example, why is line 1 from the combined textfile, that of the new file and not the old, while line 3 is from the old, and not the new?

Comment: I've edited/formatted your post; is this what you wanted? Please also explain what _"I also don't know how to group items"_ is supposed to mean. Please [click edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1379902/edit) to fix the examples. Even better: please clearly include "file 1" and "file 2" in each example line, so we know where the combined output is supposed to come from.

Comment: Oh, that _"I also don't know how to group items"_ was [about not knowing how to format the text](https://superuser.com/revisions/1379902/2)? See https://superuser.com/help/formatting I've now removed that text. Still then, the examples are really bad. But I also voted to close as you don't even seem to be around for clarifications. If closed, it may be re-opened once you clarify.

Comment: I think I can only do the merging manually. I'll try the tool from the answer below. Will be back for updates shortly. Thanks for trying to answer and understand the contents of the question!

Comment: That downvote is mine, for not fixing your examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use for that the free and open-source [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/).

This tool can visually compare up to three files, with multiple comparison
options. You may individually merge changes one-by-one or merge
all changes at once.
WinMerge will also detect cases where a group of lines is replaced by
a group with more or less lines.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I'll try this tool for merging those two files. Will give an update shortly.

Comment: Well it may not be the complete answer to the two files merging to one question, but it led the way to help me combine their changes side by side together, so I will take this as a good answer. Thanks again for helping!